# Unable to list / upload from / to Sharepoint using Office365-REST-Python-Client as a background task even after auth success using client details

Tags: python, sharepoint

I'm running this script in PowerShell :

https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/folders/get_folder_files.py

Auth is successfull using clientID and secret key.

But I get this error when trying to list files :

office365.runtime.client_request_exception.ClientRequestException: (None, None, '403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: [https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/Web/defaultDocumentLibrary/RootFolder?$select=Files&$expand=Files'](https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/Web/defaultDocumentLibrary/RootFolder?$select=Files&$expand=Files%27))

My Azure admin has granted FileReadWrite access policies yet still it doesn't list.

```
site_url = "https://xxx.mydomain.com/sites/SOF"
```

Is there anything more that I have to do in the Azure portal ?

```
HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/SOF/_api/Web/defaultDocumentLibrary/RootFolder?$select=Files&$expand=Files
```